# How to skip error cloudflare and continue with other resoucre

Tags: bash, devops, cloudflare

I am trying to run and generate resource for cloudflare but there is error to be able to run all the resource in the array for the script.

The error is :

```
FATA[0006] Could not route to /client/v4/accounts/access/certificates, perhaps your object identifier is invalid? (7003)
```

The resource that failed is cloudflare_access_mutual_tls_certificate

The script array is just minimum here, but would like the script to skip error and continue with the next in the array if one of the resource in the array failed.

```
#!/bin/bash


set -e
examplearray=("cloudflare_access_application" "cloudflare_access_bookmark" "cloudflare_access_ca_certificate" "cloudflare_access_group" 
"cloudflare_access_identity_provider" "cloudflare_zone_settings_override")

for example in ${examplearray[@]}; do
    echo Extracting $example ...
    cf-terraforming generate --resource-type $example > $example.txt
    content=$(cat $example.txt)

done
```

Comment: do you know what `set -e` does? from `set --help` => `-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.` soooo ... perhaps remove the `set -e` ... ?

Comment: `cf-terraforming || continue`?

Comment: @markp-fuso regardless have tried to run it without set -e and is giving the same error

Comment: are you saying that when you remove the `set -e` the script still stops after the 1st error, ie, it doesn't continue to process the rest of the array? or are you really asking to mask/hide the error *message* while continuing with processing of the rest of the array? stopping/starting is different from masking/hiding an error message

Comment: Yes, it stop from processing array. But is now working with this cf-terraforming generate --resource-type $example > $example.txt  || continue

Comment: @tripleee. it works with this and thanks alot cf-terraforming generate --resource-type $example > $example.txt || continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `continue` in the case of error.

The array seems entirely unnecessary (just enumerate the values directly as arguments to the `for` loop) but here's a light refactoring.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
examplearray=("cloudflare_access_application" "cloudflare_access_bookmark" "cloudflare_access_ca_certificate" "cloudflare_access_group" 
"cloudflare_access_identity_provider" "cloudflare_zone_settings_override")

# notice quotes for robustness
for example in "${examplearray[@]}"; do
    # diagnostics should go to stderr
    echo "Extracting $example ..." >&2
    content=$(cf-terraforming generate --resource-type "$example") || continue
    echo "$content" > "$example".txt
done
```